# Making an image show up at random times.JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to make an image show up at random times (or every 1-2 minutes) with JavaScript. Not looking for a code (since this is homework), but what would I need to use to make this happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout to set interval that image will appear, and set the delay to random time that could be 1-2 minutes. I found these article, maybe can halp you to do your homework

- About setTimeout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout
- About to get random times between two numbers https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-random-number-in-given-range-using-javascript/